How to create a trigger to track the total weight of all edges in a Memgraph database?
I am working with a graph in Memgraph that has weighted edges. I'd like to set up a trigger that will keep track of the total weight of all edges in the network.
Here is an example of the graph structure:

Nodes represent different cities.
Edges represent roads between these cities.
Each edge has a weight that signifies the distance between two cities.

For instance:
(A)-[10]->(B)
(B)-[20]->(C)
(A)-[15]->(C)

In this example:

The edge between A and B has a weight of 10.
The edge between B and C has a weight of 20.
The edge between A and C has a weight of 15.

The total weight in this example would be 45.

You could try playing around with triggers with the event type UPDATE.
The idea would be to have one node not related to your graph with property total_weight and create a trigger that updates the total_weight of that node every time a weight property is updated in any other node.
